# Understanding Gatsby 2 pages dependency tree

Tags: gatsby

I am having trouble understanding the loading dependencies of `gatsby 2.0.6` `pages` components.

For instance, I have the following structure:

```
/components/header.tsx  // console.log('header.tsx')
/components/home.tsx  // console.log('home.tsx') consumes header.tsx
/components/test.tsx  // console.log('test.tsx') consumes header.tsx

/pages/404.tsx      // console.log('404.tsx') consumes home.tsx
/pages/index.tsx    // console.log('INDEX.tsx') consumes home.tsx
/pages/test.tsx     // console.log('TEST.tsx') consumes test.tsx
```

Regardless of which page I load in the browser (`/` or `/test`)
The browser always logs BOTH of the components

```
header.tsx
home.tsx
404.tsx
INDEX.tsx
test.tsx
TEST.tsx
```

I would have assumed that loading a single page (e.g. `/test`) would only load and source its own dependency components (e.g. `header.tsx`, `test.tsx`, and `TEST.tsx`), and nothing outside of its tree. And certainly nothing on the other pages.

I am clearly mistaken. I have been searching for docs to explain this. Any thoughts (or doc references) on this?

And more importantly, is there a way around this?

Comment: Can the person who downvoted explain the reason? I am reasonably sure this is s a well written, specific question, It's not terribly helpful to just downvote. If you have a concern, take the 30 seconds to explain it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

RESOLVED: The issue ended up being that `gatsby develop` does not have code splitting (yet).

I filed [issue #8472](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/8472) in gatsby.

Team (kakadiadarpan) response:

> In development build, we don't have code splitting yet, while it is
>   there in the production build. There's an issue which is already open
>   for fixing the code splitting in the development build. Once that
>   issue is fixed, this will also be fixed along with that.
>
> Closing this in favor of #8342